# Custom HTML5 NumberField always fails validation

Tags: python, django, forms, html, widget

I have a simple custom NumberField:

```
class NumberInput(forms.widgets.Input):
    input_type = 'number'

class NumberField(forms.DecimalField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.widget = kwargs.get('widget', NumberInput)
        self.min_value = kwargs.get('min', 0)
        self.max_value = kwargs.get('max', 10)
        self.step = kwargs.pop('step', 1)
        super(NumberField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    def widget_attrs(self, widget):
        attrs = super(NumberField, self).widget_attrs(widget)
        if self.min_value is not None:
            attrs['min'] = self.min_value
        if self.max_value is not None:
            attrs['max'] = self.max_value
        if self.step is not None:
            attrs['step'] = self.step
        return attrs
```

And I use it in a form as such:

```
class TimeLog
     time = NumberField(min_value = '0', max_value = '100000', step = '0.25')
```

Every time I try and submit it, I get the same error, regardless of the input:

```
Ensure this value is greater than or equal to 0.
```

The element on page definitely has a valid value:

```
<input step="0.25" name="time" min="0" max="100000" type="number" id="id_time" value="0.25">
```

What's causing this invalidation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're initializing it with strings for min and max value, instead of integers.